# Load Spring Boot file system resource / config from project root directory instead of module's while running tests

Tags: java, file, spring-boot, resources, spring-test

I've got a Spring Boot muli-module project with a config file in its root:

```
project-root
|
\-- config
|   \-- file.yaml
|
\-- module1
|   \-- pom.xml
|
\-- module2
|   \-- src
|   |   \-- main
|   |   |   \-- ...
|   |   \-- test
|   |       \-- java
|   |           \-- test.java
|   |
|   \-- pom.xml
|
\-- module3
|   \-- pom.xml
...
|
\-- moduleN
|   \-- pom.xml
|
\-- pom.xml
```

Some classes in the modules (for example `project-root/module2/src/main/**.java`) load the `file.yaml` using

```
new FileSystemResource("config/file.yaml");
```

in their constructors successfully, but when I run `test.java`, which contains:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Test.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
public class Test {

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        String body = this.restTemplate.getForObject("/", String.class);
        assertThat(body)...
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

and the resource-loading code gets covered, I get a `FileNotFoundException` saying the `file.yaml` is expected in `project-root/module2/config` (instead of `project-root/config`). Why?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said how you're running your tests, but when you run them with Maven it changes the working directory to the directory of the module which is being built and tested. In Maven terminology, this is referred to as the `basedir` This is documented [here](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#workingDirectory). If you're running the tests in your IDE, it, presumably, mimics Maven's behaviour for consistency.